# Problem with subsurf

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I´ve been working on a car from Rocket League. First, I decided to design the "basic shape" of the body and when I added the *Subdivision Surface* modifier I had the problem you can see in the photos. By the way, the car I´m trying to make is the one in the upper right corner of the screen.

BEFORE SUBSURF:

[image]

AFTER SUBSURF:

[image]

As you can see, the front grille has some curves in front of it and I can´t fix the problem either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Why does the bevel tool create faces of different sizes?

[image]

You can find the blender file and the photos [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Al2pXp4IvAobvW0tiTta4J2gPSer)
THANKS!!!!

Comment: Please use the insert image button in the toolbar to add images inline on in the body of your question next time.

Comment: Your model has awful topology, with lots of NGons (faces with more than 4 sides) which will lead to numerous problems and difficulties, one of which is problems with modifiers like the one you find. Please use [good topology](http://topologyguides.com) on your models to avoid problems

Comment: These ngons will kill your model (as Duarte said). Please upload your .blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I'll try to help you. Rocket League is such a great game btw. I'm so addicted to it :).

Comment: I haven't looked at your blend file yet, but I agree with what others have said about avoiding n-gons. They make any surface deformations hard to predict and control.  *BUT* there's another thing you seem to be missing with subdivision surface modifiers: Try not to think of them as altering your original mesh. Instead think of your mesh as a "control cage" that lets you describe the SS "limit surface". Your goal is no longer to make a mesh that plays nice with SS, but rather one that defines your SS surface.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't post more than two links because if my reputation . Well, how can I reduce N-Gons? I have to start over?

Comment: By the way, here you can find the Blender file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3281" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3281/)

Comment: Or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81291/mesh-causing-abnormal-results-with-subsurf-modifier

Answer (score 1):

[image]Hi, your problem as already pointed out is N-gons, the highlighted area in the image was one crazy huge ngon, all I did was use the knife tool to slice it into 2 polygons (still ngons but better ones).
It is best to use quads if posible, ngons are not always bad, but in this particular case it had too many sides surrounded by small polygons (small detail), so this particular ngons was overpowering them.
search on google for topology and quad modeling.
cgcookie has some good tutorials.
good luck on your projects.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Is78yvd9nWMXQyTzRiWi1pVjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: well... click the up arrowwwwwwwwwwww.....