# Subdivision problem or other?

Tags: subdivision-surface

Why around the mouth's edges are collapsed when I used subdivision?

How to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25984/the-subdivision-modifier-keeps-causing-my-models-to-warp-inside-of-itself/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14196/what-causes-odd-deformations-when-using-subsurf https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81291/mesh-causing-abnormal-results-with-subsurf-modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79280/problem-with-subsurf